# MySQL : Get status (pending and approved) count for each user

Tags: mysql

I am working on a project and I'm stuck on a point. The issue is I have the following two tables, `users` and `user_mistakes`:

**`users`**:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | ABC |
| 2 | XYZ |
| 3 | JKL |

**`user_mistakes`**:

| id | user_id | mistake | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Lorem ipsum | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | Lorem ipsum | 1 |
| 3 | 2 | Lorem ipsum | 0 |
| 4 | 2 | Lorem ipsum | 1 |

If `user_mistakes.status = 0` = **pending**

If `user_mistakes.status = 1` = **approved**

According to the above `users` and `user_mistakes` table data, **I want pending and approved status count** for each user as a follows:

| user_id | name | pending_mistakes | approved_mistakes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ABC | 0 | 2 |
| 2 | XYZ | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | JKL | 0 | 0 |

Is there any way that I can achieve this with single query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with following code :

```
SELECT
    users.id,users.name,
    SUM(IF(mistakes.status=1, 1, 0)) AS approved_mistakes,
    SUM(IF(mistakes.status=0, 1, 0)) AS pending_mistakes
FROM users
LEFT JOIN mistakes ON mistakes.user_id = users.id
GROUP BY mistakes.user_id
```

Let me know if you face any issue

Answer (score 0):

Select pendingmistakes, count(pendingmistakes) from user_mistakes group by pendingmistakes